# Learning Perl or Java for Object Oriented Programming (OOP)

Tags: java, perl, oop

My programming teacher is giving us a decision to make, learn in Perl or Java for object oriented programming, which should we choose and why?

Thanks.

Comment: @Abhinav,  modern perl have Moose object. it have very good oo.

Comment: Perl does OO just fine. And it's not just locked into the inheritance model of behavior reuse. Download [`Class::Delegator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Delegator) and you have syntax sugar for aggregation/delegation. Aspect-oriented programming? With Java they had to hack the compiler to get that--Perl provides you with the tools for more OO paradigms. (ruby too.) Since the idea is *learning*, you'd *learn* more with Perl--you learn a toolset with Java. You can *explore* OOP with Perl.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ: the fact that you need an external library to do OOP sensibly is a good clue that Perl isn't the best language for learning OOP.  Granted, perl is probably easier to learn overall.

Comment: @Abhinav You say that as if it is a bad thing.

Comment: ... as an early adopter of Java (1998), I emailed Sun with a suggestion for aggregation syntax in Java to make writing all the proxies and mutators as easy as declaring them. It's now 2010. You can trace Damian's [`Class::Delegation`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Delegation) (the kernel idea for the zippier [`Class::Delegator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Delegator)) to 2001. Modern Java-ists think it's no problem, because Eclipse does all that stuff and more (Yay, Eclipse!) What was Eclipse written in? Java...*scores* of classes without those neat features of Eclipse.

Comment: What's your purpose or intention? Is it to learn just enough to pass a test for a course? Or are you making an educational investment in order to generate better job/income opportunities in the future? Or are you playing around and enjoying being able to show and talk about having attended a course on the magical world of OOP?

Comment: Get a better programming teacher? If he had said Java or Python he would have given you a reasonable choice with sensible options.

Comment: Why are you limited to those two? Although I've programmed plenty of OO in Perl, I didn't really get it until I learned Smalltalk, where everything, including the world you run it in, is an object.

Answer (score 21):

I think you are putting the cart before the horse. The first questions to consider are if you already know a programming language and if you can program well. If the answers are affirmative, you might already be applying some object oriented concepts without being aware of it.

So, your first task is to understand what object oriented programming is about, reading up on encapsulation, polymorphism, inheritance versus composition etc. Once you are comfortable with those concepts, you can adapt to whatever paradigm is facilitated by your language of choice.

Just because Java forces you to treat pretty much everything as an object does not mean all Java programs are automatically good examples of object oriented programming.

Similarly, just because Perl allows you to do crazy things, it does not mean you cannot apply principles of object oriented programming.

For Perl, [Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/) provides a lot of power. Once you have a grasp of the basics, you should read [Moose::Manual::Unsweetened](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aUnsweetened) to get a brief overview of both object oriented programming in plain Perl and the sugar Moose provides.

Comment: Given the lack of details in his post and making the assumption his motivation is to actually acquire the knowledge beyond just passing the course, I think you're correct. He is putting the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 19):

The respective OO models presented by Java and Perl each offer distinct advantages but also distinct gotchas.

Type erasure in Java prevents certain sorts of OO techniques that rely on dynamic, run-time typing.

Mixing in Java generics can make declarations even more confusing than ever they were in C, and you may never be able to do what you want to do with them. In Perl, generics are simplicity itself.

Vanilla, un-Moosed Perl can be confusing for beginners who need to get past the mechanics of where to store the state for class vs object data members.

If what you want to do with objects fits Java’s model, then you should have no problem with Java.  But if it doesn’t, you really have no choice. For some things, there are painful work-arounds, but for many, there are none and you have to learn to do without.

Perl's OO model is by far richer, but that may not be a nuance easily appreciated by the novice.  From delegation to autoloading to hot-swapping/monkey-patching classes’ methods with logging wrappers to a great deal more, there is next to nothing that you **cannot** do with Perl’s object system — one way or the other.

If you want to learn about the pleasures and pitfalls of operator overloading, then you have to choose Perl because Java simply doesn’t support that.

If you want to play around with different method-resolution strategies, you similarly have no such flexibility in Java.

If you wish to study multiple inheritance, Java is not a good choice. Especially in conjunction with different MRO, Perl gives you quite a bit to play with here.

Although it may be possible to use Java’s Classloader to simulate some of what Perl’s AUTOLOAD mechanism for method generation can do for you, I’ve never heard of anyone seriously using it for that.

If you want to talk about classes and methods indirectly, which you really do need to do more often than you might at first imagine, this is utterly straightforward in Perl, where you can just use a variable instead of a literal wherever you would put a classname of a method name.

In contrast, this requires a complicated and unintuitive hack in Java bolted on using its reflection facilities.

There is IMHO no good solution in Java for closures, something that in Perl again just follows naturally from the texture and mechanics of the language. So if you want to include certain functional programming techniques in your classes, you will have to swim upstream in Java.

There do exist workarounds in Java to not having function pointers, but again this reliance on “patterns” for workaround points to fundamental design decisions that work against you. Some would call these bugs, but they’re really bounds established by the language designers about what sorts of programming the language makes easy, what sorts it makes very tricky, and what sorts it makes impossible. If you are more comfortable with one set of boundaries than you are with another set, this makes your choice easy.  But you need to be aware of them.

It’s too bad that you were given only those two programming languages for choices.  You could learn a lot by studying other systems as well, such as Smalltalk (or perhaps later Eiffel) on one hand, and Go on another. There are key simplicities that you will miss out on just by studying only Java or Perl alone.

Whatever one system you study, you run the risk of equating OO with the bounds set by that particular language’s design.  This is very unfortunate, because those bounds are not solid reality, just a temporary illusion: for there are other OO universes where distinct fundamental axioms lead to entirely different ways of progamming.

Comment: Elegantly put. You should write books ;)))

Comment: @DVK, You guys know something about tchrist that I don't. Is he like *chromatic* or somebody?

Comment: @Axeman Hint: see http://www.perl.com/

Comment: @Axeman => `perldoc perltoot`

Comment: like chromatic? That's the wrong comparison. You should be asking if chromatic is like tchrist. Google "tchrist perl" (and not the "christ perl" Google wants to autocorrect for you). I think this would make a good interview question. If you don't recognize the "tchrist" handle, you probably don't know Perl that well, and there's a very particular and uncommon reason for that. If someone don't recognize my name you can't make the same conclusion, for instance.

Comment: Also. tchrist's recent postings in p5p about Java and its regex support have been rather interesting.

Comment: Just an example: http://www.xray.mpe.mpg.de/mailing-lists/perl5-porters/2010-12/msg00240.html

Answer (score 12):

Before reading the answers and comments here, I had no problem accepting that Java was the Pascal/Basic of OO programming--as well as one of the most current and marketable languages out there. And I have no great antipathy for Java as a current language. As I commented above I was an early adopter of Java. If you look on my profile, I identify myself as a "Java and Perl programmer" because that's what I am.

As much as I like Perl, I didn't feel the need to *answer* and say "Perl!". It *might* not be the right language for your class to learn. Some rather procedural-looking Java that I have seen aside, it's hard *not* to write OO code in Java. OO is built into the language. It's a *good* choice for programming OO or learning OO.

#### Java is Simpler

- Java is *safe*, Perl is a little too hackable--once you have injected code inside the environment. There are strategies to minimize this risk, but still code that you have accepted inside the system *can* fool with accepted code in another part.
- Java is fully encapsulated (though you can break that with careless design). Although Perl has [Inside-Out objects](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?inside_out_object) which make objects opaque to each other. They have never overtaken the "blessed hash" model that permiates Perl OO. And as they are simply hashes, all their "fields" are there for you to play with (which makes some automated testing easier than JUnit).

Perl has solved the problem with encapsulation by *manners*. We Perlers are of the opinion that you never needed that much object *security* in the first place, and that objects and subroutines keeping their hands to themselves is usually good enough. Most dynamic languages have been advanced by this practice as Python, Ruby, JavaScript all allow "reaching in" just as much as Perl does.

Sooner or later when you mess with some other objects internal data--it will bite you. You will troubleshoot it and find that you should have respected data that you had not fully owned or explored every implication of--I guarantee you it will happen if you do not heed the ancient wisdom, my son.

- Java is quite a bit more marketable and has a bigger toolset.

#### Perl is Multi-Paradigm

Perl is a multi-paradigm language. It's not unique in this. So are most of the dynamic languages: JavaScript, Python, Ruby, .... Well, they extend to [*Functional Programming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_Programming) but not so much to [*Declarative Programming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) (like Prolog)--although there are modules for that. ([`AI::Prolog`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AI%3a%3aProlog), [`Language::Prolog::Types`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Language%3a%3aProlog%3a%3aTypes)).

But that aside, Perl does OO well-enough. In fact the simple OO scheme where you can declare all your classes in a single file (not recommended for production systems, however), it's easy to write simple examples of polymorphic objects that you can just run and test.

This is one of the places that Java is not simpler: building your executable. Java *can* be simple--and used to be simple, but now you have a list of actions that need to be performed to get an executable out of a group of source files.

Perl, as a dynamic language, is (best case) write-and-run.

As I mentioned in my comments under the post, Perl let's you *explore* OO. It isn't simply inheritance-based polymorphism. [`Class::Delegator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aDelegator) provides declarative delegative syntax. [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) provides *roles* and *mixins* and *point cuts*.

You can *learn* more OO with Perl, because it gives you more tools.

#### Last Word about Java

One more thing about the guts of Perl. Almost every really neat thing that I've seen in the Java world is done with *reflection* or dynamic code generation and compilation--or even like AspectJ--hacking the compiler! Javaists talk about their bullet-proof language with great pride, meanwhile to get around the prison walls of Java, they too often cannot resist the dynamic appeal of `Class.forName` (which blows up if it cannot find the class) if they are not rewiring things through reflection.

So if you don't know Java, and haven't spent anytime reading production Java code or seeing the practices in the field, you could just buy the hype here. That all this market share is built up from the adaptability of Java--which is much safer and less mucky than Perl guts.

And C++/Java-style templates *break* encapsulation and can no less eyesores than Perl code.

#### Last Word about Perl

Perl is a magical land, where wizards can cast spells and counter-spells and counter-counter-spells (...) to try to keep the wizards of other distributions from screwing up their magic.

I've seen a lot messy perl and Sorceror's Apprentice Perl tricks that foul the Perl Ether. I've seen Perl where the programmer didn't not know that Perl does while loops, let alone transforms.

But then again, I haven't often seen 1200+ line Perl subs that I have seen in Java EJBs if-else-try-catch-jungles. (*No readability problem there!*). 
Because Perl allows you to express what you want to do in much fewer lines. So 200+ line if-jungle subs take their place--and their almost as *ghastly*.

Comment: Agreed on everything you say.  I do not understand why they teach only Java and never teach C.  This is backwards. One should learn C first. It makes you appreciate — and sometimes unappreciate — Java all the more that way. It certainly brings better understanding of programming.

Answer (score 11):

Try them both.  Use the one that clicks.

Java and Perl are diametrically opposed philosophically.  Java is about strict types, strict structure and orthogonal language design.  Perl is all about flexibility and expressiveness.  Java is a small language with a big pile of libraries to learn.  Perl is a huge language that you need only learn a bit of to use.

In Java the OOP system is baked into the language, and there is only one true way to do things.  It's chock full of ideas about best practices and strictly controlling information flow between objects.

In Perl, you are given the bare minimum facilities needed to build objects (a way to bind a variable to set of code, an inheritance system and namespaces).  It's up to you to use these facilities effectively.  This flexibility is what allowed Moose to happen.  It also allowed the failed (IMO) experiments with inside-out objects.  Damian Conway's book Object Oriented Perl goes into great detail about different ways that you can put the system to use.

You can learn a lot and be productive with either language.  Try them both, and either pick one or do your homework in both languages simultaneously.  If you pick one, pick the one that fits.

Comment: Agreed: you will learn far more about OO than the simple sum of their separate approaches if you learn them both.  If you learn only one, you will learn less about OO than you could.

Answer (score 10):

Java. You're learning OOP, right? OOP in Java is far simpler than you'll find in Perl. You will find the tool support available for Java (e.g. Eclipse) of great benefit in finding your way round OOP.

I write OO Perl also, but it's a far harder language to master, especially when starting out. Also, the tool support isn't as helpful as you'll find in Java. Come back to Perl after a couple of years with Java - and learn a modern style, as you'll find in chromatic's [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/).

Comment: +1 for Modern perl link

Answer (score 8):

I've been using Perl for almost 20 years, and there are many, many times I select it over Java.  But I'm going to recommend that if those are your choices, learn Java.  It's more strongly typed than Perl and will help foster good coding habits.  If you're in high school headed for college, Java is now the language of choice in 100- and 200-level CS courses, so learning it now will give you a leg up.

Perl's great, but it's like a Swiss Army chainsaw.  You can do a lot of very powerful things with it or you can cut off a limb trying.

Comment: +1 for the chainsaw

Comment: This. Perl is a great tool but a horrible way to learn OOP. You may succeed but you will (1) probably be scarred for life and (2) take a lot longer. I can testify to this personally based on having learned OOP using Perl. I cannot recommend it.

Comment: Sorpigal: did you use Moose?

Answer (score 0):

I vote for Java, for learning OOP, if you are restricted to just those 2 languages.

On the other hand, understanding OOP is about the concepts, not any particular language, so if you have a firm grasp of the concepts you certainly can use any language you want.  But I think Java servers better in this case...

Comment: And your extensive (or any) list of reasons?

Comment: @dvk, added more words for you.

Comment: out of curiousity, what is Perl's niche?

Comment: Perl has a niche? In my experience it sprawls out over everything like a dog on the bed at night.

Comment: @michael -- lol, yes thats its niche.  A long time ago I buit some xmpp clients with perl.  It was awesome.  You finish the code and its looks like real code.   Then in 2 weeks you don't remember how anything works

Comment: hvgotcodes: I recommend reading "Modern Perl" book, Perl changed much from "long time ago".

Comment: @Michael Carman - yikes! Now you made me afraid of ever owning a dog!

Comment: @hvgotcodes - not to try to be insulting, but if you don't remember how your code works 2 weeks after you built it, it's ONLY a reflection of your skills as software developer and not of the language. My code - be it Perl, Java, C++ (or probably Scheme if I was using a functional language these days) all looks 100% identically readable and maintainable. So does any good software developer's.

Comment: @dvk.  don't worry, I'm pretty much immune to statements like that.  You didn't detect my hyperbole, that's all.  You are telling me modern Perl doesn't look like http://jjnapiorkowski.typepad.com/modern-perl/2010/01/index.html?  My point was that the syntax of perl is very specific.  When you step away from it, its easy to not remember how it works.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: If when you step away from Perl, you no longer remember how its syntax works, then you never learned it in the first place. This is the same argument for not letting kids have a summer break, claiming that the break makes them forget; it doesn’t — it just separates those who never learned the topic in the first place from those who did.

Comment: @hvgotcodes - Actually, I'd tell you exactly that. You're looking at an RFC (not finished code) for a complicated pattern using full capabilities of Moose (if a comparable Java code could be even written at all - which I'm not certain of - it'd look just as complicated). We were talking about Perl OOP for beginners, so compare basic Java Class of your coosing to basic Moose class: http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-1.21/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Basics/Recipe1.pod ; Also, just because that code sits on modern Perl website, doesn't mean it's a paragon of readability - as i said it's an RFC.

Comment: @ysth: `perl -E'say niche =~ s/h//r'` ☺

Comment: @tchrist -- i never said i disagreed with your previous 'statement' ;).  Seems like Perl6 has done things like add a 'class' keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Learning Java would give you knowledge of a "C-style" language - a group which includes C, C++, Objective-C, and C#. Games and system software are most frequently implemented in the first three, while C# and Java are often used for enterprise computing and web application development.

Perl is sufficiently idiosyncratic that knowledge of its syntax is less transferable. There are some domains, such as bioinformatics, where it has been popular.

I believe that undergrad introductory programming courses are more frequently taught in Java than in Perl.

For a college-bound student, the choice will depend to some degree on what he or she is bound to do there.

Comment: Also, looking to your future learning - Perl makes it easier to apply ideas from functional programming, whereas doing the same in Java is not so straightforward. However, Java can be used as a stepping-stone to languages like Scala or Clojure, which run on the JVM.

Comment: you can write perfectly C-like code in Perl (sadly :) ). So 100% of Perl's C-like syntax is transferable to any other C-like language.

Answer (score -1):

This is just my opinion but when I tried learning OO concepts in Perl I had trouble and Java just sort of clicked. I should mention that I first leaned to program in Perl, so I wasn't put off by the language itself.

Another benefit of choosing Java is that you'll find a lot more jobs and you'll be putting all of those OO concepts to use.

Comment: Try Moose and MooseX::Declare for OOP.

Comment: Well, to be fair, you'll probably have trouble with the first language you choose because the concepts are new, and an easier time with the second language because you learned more than you thought from the first language.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should first master the basic concepts of OOP, like Classes, Objects, Encapsulation, Inheritance, and Polymorphism. Once you have mastered the concept then you can begin with the syntax. 
In my experience Java syntax is easy than Perl as Perl uses hashes for objects. So if you want to spend more time on concept and less on syntax then go for Java.

Comment: I disagree with your suggesting that he first master basic abstract concepts. Learning the abstractions without simultaneously learning via concrete experience isn't a good strategy for +95% of the people. I will grant you that learning the concepts via the concrete experience of a particular implementation language will likely leave the learner in a place where the language syntax and the OOP semantics are collapsed (i.e. undistinguished). However, that distinction can be gained later by learning an additional OOP language.

Comment: Which part of `$my_obj->myMethod()` in perl is significantly harder syntax wise compared to Java's `my_obj.myMethod()`? One extra character in the method call operator?

Comment: to DVK: it is not about calling object methods that make it hard to learn OOP in Perl, it is about defining the class, packages, class veriables. He needs to learn hash, hashref, blessing etc.. While Moose make it easy to do OOP then again he need to know CPAN, modules installations etc. I think he should mention his experience with both languages, so we can give him an advice based on his exp. BTW I prefer Perl over Java.

Comment: to chaotic: I know for some people it hard learn a concept without concrete example, and therefore I mentioned at the end Java might be a good option but again it depends on his experience with both languages.

Comment: (state, behavior, identity) ≆ (encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism)

Comment: I don't know why I get down voted even though a lot of  Perl programmers are saying to learn OOP in Java. You can disagree with my opinions, however it doesn't mean that I am suggesting anything wrong.

Comment: @Ibrahim - I upvoted a comment that said Java, but I utterly disagree with your statement abut syntax, considering Moose etc... I didn't downvote you but whoever did probably agreed with this.

Comment: If you think Perl objects are hashes, you've missed the point of Perl objects.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you learning these languages for? The answer should determine which to chose.

For example if you plan to get a job, I would search job sites in your area for the type of jobs that interest you and see what skills they are asking for.

e.g. on jobserver.co.uk, jobs earning £50K+

```
perl - 165
java - 2273
```

Note: some people find perl related jobs more interesting, but if you have no opinion one way or another, then Java may be the best choice.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote, or just not the answer you want to hear?

Comment: @Peter I did not vote your answer down. However, would you be demanding an explanation if someone had voted your answer up because it was the answer "she wanted to hear"?

Comment: @Sinan, I may have something to learn from people who don't agree with me, I don't expect to learn much from people who figure my answer makes sense. I am not often wrong on certain matters, but when I am, I take note.

Comment: Even when I'm right, I could make myself clearer or better understand where others are coming from.  There is always something to learnt, but just down voting is like saying I could tell you what you don't know but I'm not going to tell you.

Comment: There's another important number: how many people are looking for perl vs java jobs?

Comment: @ysth: I have another number for you: how often do you hear people say how much they *enjoyed* writing a project in Java versus how many said the same about writing in Perl? There’s quite a disparity there, and I think it’s important to reflect on the whys and wherefores behind it.

Comment: @tchrist: agreed; the company I'm currently contracting for is doing some things in Python because it's so hard to find good Perl programmers locally who aren't already happily employed.

Comment: @ysth, A high number of vacancies should reflect a relative low number of people looking/able. Admittedly not always a good thing.  I did point out that some people find Perl project more interesting. Java vs Perl might not be the best two options, Python, Ruby, Scala, Groovy etc might be a better choice.

Comment: IMHO, What is interesting is subjective and can only be judged by the OP. The job numbers are less of an opinion, but what you make of the numbers is another question.

Comment: See by the downvotes on other answers a common theme. I suspect PERL fans are more passionate/emotional than Java fans. ;)

Answer (score -4):

+1 for Java. I've never seen a Perl application that is large and nicely structured at the same time. One commenter perfectly said "Perl is good for Perl orientated programming" - there is nothing to add ;-)

So if you want to learn OO concepts I strongly recommend that you use Java.

Comment: I've never seen Visual Basic code that wasn't a goto mess either--except modular stuff that *I* wrote. Most of the JavaScript on most of the pages, pre-2000, was procedural if-trees, I coded OO-JavaScript from the beginning. Structure is a matter of design and discipline. I coded Java for longer than I've coded Perl, but I never made the 600+ line if-tree EJB methods (that remind me of 600+ line PL/I subroutines) that seem to populate so much enterprise code. I've ***seen*** them a bunch of times. I've modified hundreds. I've modified 200+ line Perl subs too. I just don't *write* them.

Comment: And I have never seen someone who was a good developer who wasn't smart enough to realize that "I saw examples of bad code" != "The language is bad".

Comment: Of course I didn't imply that you **cannot** write good OO code in Perl. But as a beginner you might want to look for example applications to get an idea of how X is done in Y. Sorry if that offends anyone but most of the Perl stuff I have seen so far is far away from being a good teaching example. No, that doesn't say anything about Perl in general, but in my opinion: If Perl makes it easy for you to code badly (which it seems to do according to all these examples) a beginner should be kept at a fair distance.

Comment: @perdian:  The short answer is that you can write crappy code in any language, including the ones that purport to enforce good practice.

Comment: @perdian, if you're talking about Eckel's *Thinking In Java*, yeah there are a lot of good clean examples out there. If you're talking about Java out in the field, I don't think there are that many clean examples as you seem to think. Toy code can be written *cleanly* in almost any language. YMMV.

Comment: @Blrfl: Absolutely! But there seem to be some languages that make it a bit easier to "misbehave" than others. Compare C++ to Java and I think nobody will disagree that C++ is far more "attractive" to people not wanting to really care about good style - and that's my impression of Perl as well. And for the record: yes, I've seen a lot of crappy Java apps as well :)

Comment: In less-strict languages (C, C++, Perl, BASIC, assembly), writing good code just requires that you have a full understanding of what you're doing and the discipline to carry it off without getting sloppy.  Strict languages like Pascal and Ada enforce discipline but make it a huge pain in the butt to do kinky things when you've thought long and hard and determined that it's the right thing.  (Pascal lacks basic loop controls like `break` and `continue`, for example.)  Java is a happy medium.

Comment: @Blrfl: Java falls in the Pascal and Ada category of enforcing Right Thinking™.  Doing anything interesting in Java requires breaking out of that restrictive box: reflection, ClassLoader hacks, cortortions with generics, etc. That doesn’t sound happy-medial to me; it sounds hackish.

Comment: It's all relative, Tom.  From Perl's vantage point along the strictness spectrum, I would agree.  I've done extensive development at both ends and in the middle (including large systems in Perl) and think that lumping Java in with Pascal and Ada is like lumping Colorado in with California because, relative to Washington, D.C., because both are somewhere out west.  Java isn't the right tool for every job any more so than Perl, and the practical reality in my life has been you can't give everyone the pointy tools.  Not all of them have the chops to handle them without getting stabbed in the leg.